# svn update to remote url not work in subversion 1.7.2

Tags: svn

Recently I updated SUbversion on my server from 1.5 to 1.7.2, and run the command:
 svn update https://xxx
and it does not work anymore. It returns
  svn:E205000: The xxx is not a local path
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile svn with `neon` support, which can access a repository via WebDAV protocol.

You can use `svn --version` to check whether your svn has neon support, something like this:

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.7.1 (r1186859)
....

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
```

Answer (score 9):

I have a build script that switches between an update or a checkout depending on the situation. It previously looked something like this:

```
svn update "http://xxx" "c:\xxx"
```

or this

```
svn checkout "http://xxx" "c:\xxx"
```

The previous version of subversion we used would allow this however what I have discovered is that after updating to 1.7.2 the update command does not like you specifying the repository and gives the "not a local path" error. After all it doesn't need it and what I now use when updating is simply:

```
svn update "c:\xxx"
```

Comment: I have a question about the last part of your answer...: How do you specify the repository´s URL in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Try using **svn upgrade**.  This is a new command added to convert working copies of old format to comply with the new SVN ver. 1.7. standards, refer to [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.upgrade.html). But be warned that this is **unrecoverable** - this new type of working copy will not work with SVN clients older than 1.7 version.

Comment: I tried svn upgrade to but it still says that the url is not a local path. Only svn co could work. Did Subversion change their policy on these commands?

Answer (score 1):

yep : after the svn checkout I only needed to do : svn update LOCALFOLDER for updating my svn folder formerly checku