# How to iterate through items in an .ini file with a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ini

I am currently trying to loop through every item from a `.ini` file and to work with the values later on. But I can't figure out how. My `config.ini` file looks like this:

```
[items]
item_1=XXXXX
item_2=XXXXX
item_3=XXXXX
item_4=XXXXX

[SomeSection]
......
```

I found a way to iterate and echo every item from the `config.ini` file, like so:

```
@echo off 
for /F %%i in (config.ini) do (
   echo %%i
)
```

My problem is that I want to work with specific values. So I have to check the categorie and the keys from the `config.ini` file. I tried using this, but I ran into errors:

```
@echo off 
for /F %%i in (config.ini) do (
   SET item = %%i
   if %item%==[items] (
      rem do something here with the key and values now
   )
 )
```

As I already mentioned, I am not able to save the values to another variable, which leads to my problem that I can't work with them.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What "check the categorie and the keys from the config.ini file" means? If you do this: `for /F %%i in (config.ini) do set %%i` you _define variables_ with the values in the .ini file. For example: `set item_1=XXXXX`, `set item_2=XXXXX`, etc

Comment: `SET item = %%i` should read `set item=%%i` or `set "item=%%i"`; then you'd need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to read the set variable in the loop; or you simply change the condition `if "%%i"=="[items]"`. Though this just fixes the syntax issues…

Comment: A simple approach could be this (not tested): `for /F "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /I /N /C:"[items]" "config.ini"') do set "SKIP=%%N"`, then `for /F "usebackq skip=%SKIP% delims==" %%I in ("config.ini") do if not "%%J"=="" echo/%%I` (first get position of `[items]`, then skip such as many lines, stopping as soon as there is no more value, which it true for the next section header)

Comment: @aschipfl I tried your code and it works fine but how could I break the loop if the `[items]` sections ends?

Comment: Is the filename variable in the ini file then without an extention, seeing as you provided it with one? i.e `!filename!.xml`? secondly, you are using `!filename!` obviously in the loop, but did you `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` in the beginning of the script?

Comment: @Gerhard Yes, I used `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the beginning.

Comment: @Gerhard Error: `svn: E205000: Try 'svn help log' for more information
svn: E205000: 'extensions' option requires 'diff' option`. It a tortoise (svn program I use) error, but they appear because of the values I use, because its working fine without using the values.

Comment: that is an error on `svn` itself, not sure but perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646990/svn-update-to-remote-url-not-work-in-subversion-1-7-2) will help.

Comment: @MΛIK, replace my original `if` condition in the loop by `if "%%J"=="" (goto :NEXT) else echo/%%I` and put the label `:NEXT` into the next line after the loop to break it…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quite simple approach was to determine the line number of the target section header in advance, then skip such as many lines when reading the configuration file, stopping as soon as there occurs another string enclosed within brackets:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_CONFIG=%~dp0config.ini" & rem // (path to configuration file)
set "_SECT=items"             & rem // (section name without brackets)

rem // Clean up variables whose names begin with `$`:
for /F "delims==" %%V in ('2^> nul set "$"') do set "%%V="
rem // Gather number of line containing the given section (ignoring case):
for /F "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /N /I /X /C:"[%_SECT%]" "%_CONFIG%"') do set "SKIP=%%N"
rem // Read configuration file, skipping everything up to the section header:
for /F "usebackq skip=%SKIP% delims=" %%I in ("%_CONFIG%") do (
    rem // Leave loop as soon as another section header is reached:
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%K in ("%%I") do if "[%%K]%%L"=="%%I" goto :NEXT
    rem // Do something with the key/value pair, like echoing it:
    echo(%%I
    rem // Assign a variable named of `$` + key and assign the value:
    set "$%%I"
)
:NEXT
rem // Return assigned variables:
set "$"

endlocal
exit /B
```

This script would assign the following variables, based on your sample configuration file:

> ```cmd
> $item_1=XXXXX
> $item_2=XXXXX
> $item_3=XXXXX
> $item_4=XXXXX
> ```