# How to use extracted variables to call a command while iterating through a .ini file in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ini

From my initial [question with code from @aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69495883/how-to-iterate-through-items-in-an-ini-file-with-a-batch-file). My goal is to iterate through a `.ini` file, extract the **keys** and **values** of an specific section and to use the extracted informations to call a command. The `config.ini` file, which I want to iterate, looks like this:

```
[Branches]
trunk=path_to_trunk
k21.1.0.Patch=path_to_k21.1.0.Patch
k21.2.0.Test=path_to_k21.2.0.Test

[Unimportant section]
......
```

I am currently iterating the `config.ini` file like suggested by [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69495883/how-to-iterate-through-items-in-an-ini-file-with-a-batch-file). Take a look at his answer to see the details.

By the way I would be very pleasured if someone could explain me where the variables, which are storing the informations, get initialized and where I could use them.

Anyways since I now should have the informations I need, **even if I don't know exactly where**, I want to run a command, based on the informations which were extracted.

The command I want to run is a [tortoise](https://tortoisesvn.net/) command, which **is working fine with absolute parameters**, but strange error messages appear when I want to pass the variables as parameters:

```
svn log PATH_TO_BRANCH -v --xml --username xxxxxx --password "xxxxxx" > BRANCH.xml
```

As you can see above in the `config.ini` file, the variable `PATH_TO_BRANCH` is the original **value** of the variable `BRANCH`, which in this case would be the **key**. Note that the variables are named differently in the suggestion of achipfl.

I would be pleasured if someone could help me out here or has any suggestions for me, how I could solve my problem.

---

## Output

Firstly, I split the varibale `$%%I` after it gets initialized, since `$%%I` contains the **key/value** pair. After that I call the command:

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ("$%%I") do (
    set "branch=%%a"
    set "path=%%b"
    cmd /c svn log %path% -v --xml --username xxxxxx --password "xxxxxx" > %branch%.xml
)
```

After running this I get this error:

```
svn: E205000: Try 'svn help log' for more information svn: 
E205000: 'extensions' option requires 'diff' option
```

As I said before I don't get this error, if I use plain text instead of variables as parameters. The command `svn help log` only gives me informations about the usage of the command. The XML file doesn't get created.

Comment: Post a [example], in the answer itself.

Comment: Besides path **to** branch and path **of** branch is different.

Comment: We can't do anything without the code.

Comment: I rolled back the question to my edit where I linked the initial question to this one. No need to repost the code.

Comment: Then back on subject. I do not know SVN, but it seems to be a gui and will therefore not emit any output to stdout. Do you get any results in `BRANCH.xml` ? If so, can you please post the most relevant parts, i.e any particular errors.

Comment: Please also show exactly how you run the `svn` command using the `cmd` variables.

Comment: Ok, there we go. You broke your systems `%PATH%` variable. `%PATH%` is a system variable, you cannot re-use it as you will break your session. rename the path variable to something like `%SVNPATH%` So Do something like: `set "svnpath=%%b"` and then `svn log %svnpath% -v --xml --username xxxxxx --password "xxxxxx" > %branch%.xml`

Comment: PS!! it is also important to close any `cmd` windows where you ran the script and open a new `cmd` in order to restore the path variable, unless you run the script by double clock, which will close the session when completed.

Comment: you still need to `set "branch=%%a"`, did you do that? alternatively do `svn log %svnpath% -v --xml --username xxxxxx --password "xxxxxx" > %%a.xml`

Comment: Let me post an answer with full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your example, you broke the systems `%path%` variable. Never use system variables as your will cause issues in the local session:

This instance does not require any variable's to be set though as you can use the metavariables:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /I /N /C:"[items]" "config.ini"') do set "SKIP=%%N"
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,* skip=%SKIP% delims==" %%I in ("config.ini") do (
    if "%%J" == "" exit /b
    svn log "%%J" -v --xml --username "xxxxxx" --password "xxxxxx" > "%%I.xml"
)
```

If you really must set variables, then:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /I /N /C:"[items]" "config.ini"') do set "SKIP=%%N"
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,* skip=%SKIP% delims==" %%I in ("config.ini") do (
    set "branch=%%I"
    set "svnpath=%%J"
    if "%%J" == "" exit /b
    svn log "!svnpath!" -v --xml --username "xxxxxx" --password "xxxxxx" > "!branch!.xml"
)
```

Comment: Nice! Let me recommend to put quotes around the gathered items in the `svn log` command line, like the repository path (`"%%I"` or `"!svnpath!"`), the redirection target file (`"%%J.xml"` or `"!branch!.xml"`) and even the user name (`"xxxxxx"`) in order to avoid problems with white-spaces or other special characters…

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl, yeah I was not 100% sure initially `svn` handles quoted words, so I played it safe just to see if OP can make it work. Edited now though.